# Проверка на уже существующий email PHP + jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

Здравствуйте! Есть форма:
https://jsfiddle.net/pkhyLvcc/

Странно, но на фидле работает на Stack'e нет. Ну да ладно, я думаю, что это не сильно мешает.

Задача такова: проверить поле `<input id='email'/>` и `<input id='name'/>` по вот такому условию

```
<?php if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query("SELECT `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'"))){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    fail = 'email is already used';
    $('#mailErr').text(fail);
    </script>";
}
?>
```

Кстати да, в SQL запросе обратные апострофы удалились.

Comment: Используйте функцию http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php А лучше подготовленные выражения http://phpfaq.ru/pdo#prepared в PDO.

Comment: @Visman Я имел в виду сделать это на стороне user'a. Это возможно через AJAX GET запрос?

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=php+ajax+%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно вынести проверку на существование email в отдельный PHP файл и по blur, или другому событию, отправлять введённый email по средствам ajax в этот файл, который в свою очередь будет возвращать true/false.

Comment: Ок, я вынес в отдельный файл проверку. Но есть еще один вопрос - по поводу email. У меня в скрипте условие, которое возвращает fail = "" (то же самое что и false, но у меня ошибки нет, когда fail - пустая строка) является условие else. Какой запрос в else if мне записать, который был бы эквивалентен mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query)?

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос.
В файле проверки нужно написать проверку
if (mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query) == 0) {
echo 'true';
}
else {
echo 'false';
}

В ajax запросе проверить значение:
$.ajax({
...
success : function(res){
if (res != 'true'){
alert('Такой email уже зарегистрирован ');
}
}
})